# How to migrate MySQL Fulltext Search from MyISAM to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, innodb

I needed to migrate from MyISAM to InnoDB. In the process I found that the app return now errors on some searches:

> 1064 syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end

Are there any significant changes or characters I have to escape? 80% of the searches work OK.

The character -- and ) and @ do not work anymore

e.g.

```
SELECT MATCH (anchor) AGAINST ('te--st' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
FROM seo_content_links

SELECT MATCH (anchor) AGAINST ('te)st' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
FROM seo_content_links 

SELECT MATCH (anchor) AGAINST ('te@st' IN BOOLEAN MODE) score
FROM seo_content_links
```

This very much looks like a bug in MySQL.

Comment: can you provide use with the actual query...

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces around `--`?  `--` is the "here comes an end-of-line comment" token.

Comment: yes. This is regular text input. I would need to escape that if this behaviour has changed. The application was working on mysql 5.5 with myisam table full text search.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a bug in MySQL 5.6.x.

One possible solution is to replace the characters in question:

`$text = addslashes(str_replace(array("--", "@", ")", "(", "-"), " ", $text));`